# What permissions should a wordpress installation have to be secure but functional?

Tags: wordpress, security, ubuntu, permissions

I've already read http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress but I can't get my head around it. What are the permissions that shall be set and by who shall it be owned by? Right now I have set as the result of the following commands:

```
# reset to safe defaults
find /usr/share/wordpress -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;
find /usr/share/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /usr/share/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

# allow wordpress to manage wp-config.php (but prevent world access)
chgrp www-data /usr/share/wordpress/wp-config.php
chmod 660 /usr/share/wordpress/wp-config.php

# allow wordpress to manage .htaccess
chgrp www-data /usr/share/wordpress/.htaccess
chmod 664 /usr/share/wordpress/.htaccess

# allow wordpress to manage wp-content
find /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content -exec chgrp www-data {} \;
find /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

After this configuration the installation is unusable. Any tips?

Comment: Are you using your own server in ubuntu or are you using a web hosting site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick recap of how I manage permissions on my servers:

- Anybody can read files and directories
- Nobody can write *anything* outside of the /wp-content/uploads directory
- PHP scripts *can not* be executed inside the /wp-content/uploads directory
- PHP scripts *can not* be executed directly in /wp-includes and /wp-content

So it doesn't matter who owns the .php files, as long as the apache user can read them. Allowing the apache user to modify these files is a risk, even .htaccess. The downside of all of this is that you'll need to provide WordPress with FTP credentials to do things like install or delete a plugin, update a theme or core, etc. That's something I can live with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I notice now that the script I used earlier actually worked when I ran through it again, I must have done something wrong last time. I'll still select your question as the accepted answer though :)